# convert text from utf to read-able text

Tags: utf-8, decode, utf8-decode

I have some UTF-Text starting with "ef bb bf". How can I turn this message to human read-able text? vim, gedit, etc. interpret the file as plain text and show all the ef-text even when I force them to read the file with several utf-encodings. I tried the "recode" tool, it doesn't work. Even php's utf8_decode failed to produce the expected text output.

Please help, how can I convert this file so that I can read it?

Comment: Perhaps it is not UTF-8, run the `file` tool on the file to see what it thinks. (or maybe you don't have the proper font to display what's in the text=

Comment: file says: _data: ASCII text_

Answer (score 1):

`ef bb bf` is the [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Strip of the first three bytes and try to `utf8_decode` the remainder.

```
$text = "\xef\xbb\xbf....";
echo utf8_decode(substr($text, 3));
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it UFT8, UTF16, UTF32? It matters a lot! I assume you want to convert the text into old-fashioned ASCII (all characters are 1 byte long).

UTF8 should already be (at least mostly) readable as it uses 1 byte for standard ASCII characters and only uses multiple bytes for special/multilingual characters (Character codes > 127). It sounds like your file isn't UTF8, or you'd already be able to read it! Online content is generally UTF-8.

Unicode character codes are the same as the old ASCII codes up to 127.

UTF16 and UTF32 always use 2 and 4 bytes respectively to encode every character, whether those characters can be represented in a single byte or not. That makes it unreadable if the text editor is expecting UTF8.

Gedit supports UTF16 and UTF32 but you need to 'add' those encoding explicitly in the open dialog box (and possibly select them explicitly instead of using auto-detect)

Comment: Someone pointed out that EF BB BF is the byte order mark of UTF8. That's seldom used for UTF8 (it's not necessary for UTF8), but if present it would be encoded in hex, so opening the file in plain text should produce 3 garbage characters, not the string "ef bb bf". It sounds like the file was produced by outputting the hex representation and piping it into a text file.